# Python error importing bottle.py on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, web-services, bottle

I've installed Python 3.3 on a Windows 7 machine. I wanted to try to the Bottle micro web
framework. I downloaded the bottle.py (latest version from their site) and put it in my app
folder.

When I do the first line in the tutorial, "from bottle import route, run, template"
I got this error message:

```
*C:\Dev>python
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from bottle import route,run,template
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".\bottle.py", line 564
    raise exc_info[0], exc_info[1], exc_info[2]
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>*
```

Any suggestions how I can fix this problem and continue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the [bottle installation instructions](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#installation).

The [latest version is published to PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bottle), you have an old version of the code there still, one that is *not* compatible with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

The format

```
raise Exception, args
```

is not there anymore in Python 3+.

That is why the statement is throwing syntax error:

```
raise exc_info[0], exc_info[1], exc_info[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

That was a bug introduced 5 days ago and fixed today. Just download bottle.py again. Or use a stable release as suggested by Martijn Pieters